# Finding substring not working

Tags: c++

This code is supposed to return yes if the string has 'nadia' no otherwise. But when I submitted it said wrong answer although it is wokring on the sample tests.? Does anyone know what I am missing?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    bool flag = false;
    bool flag2 = false;
    bool flag3 = false;
    bool flag4 = false;

    int count = 0;
    vector<string>v;
    cin >> t;
    string x;
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        {
            cin >> x;
            v.push_back(x);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            x = v[i];
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
            {
                if (x.at(i) == 'n')
                {
                    flag = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
                    {
                        if (x.at(i) == 'a')
                        {
                            ++count;
                            flag2 = true;
                            for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
                            {
                                if (x.at(i) == 'd')
                                {
                                    flag3 = true;
                                    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
                                    {
                                        if (x.at(i) == 'i')
                                        {
                                            flag4 = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if ((flag) && (flag2) && (flag3) && (flag4) && (count >= 2))
            {
                cout << "YES" << endl;

            }
            else
            {
                cout << "NO" << endl;

            }
            count = 0;
            flag = false;
            flag2 = false;
            flag3 = false;
            flag4 = false;
        }

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Sample Input:

```
3
anhaldillooa
nnaaddiiaa
nxzdiao
```

Sample Output:

```
YES
YES
NO
```

Comment: I think it was Linus Torvalds (creator of linux) who said: "If you need more than 3 levels of indentation, you are doing something wrong". Also, you are using a bunch of nested 'for' loops with same variable names everywhere. I smell bugs.

Comment: Why not just use `std::string::find`?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: Also, none of those strings in your input has "nadia" in them.  What exactly is it you're trying to solve?  What are the actual requirements?

Comment: @BłażejMichalik That can't be that accurate of a yardstick since in Java your on the third indentation when inside a method (unless it's 3 indents local to the function).

Comment: It's a bit exaggerated one, I know, Linus probably knows too. But under that exaggeration lies undeniable truth: too much nesting things does bugs. Also, Linus Torvalds works mostly in C. And he hates OOP. Which means he hates java too.

Comment: `But when i submitted it said wrong answer although it is wokring on the sample tests.`  The first thing you should do is write a very simple function to do this, regardless of the string.  A 3 or 4 line loop using `std::string::find` is all that is necessary to solve this problem.  Also, if your goal is to find if the string contains the letters `'n', 'a', 'd', 'i', 'a'`, in that order, regardless of what characters lie in between those characters, then you should state this.  Even with that requirement, a 3 or 4 line loop using `find` is all it would take to solve the problem.

Comment: And one more thing: in the code OP provided he forgot to check for last "a". Why? Because he has nesting storm in his code, and probably can't see behind 120th column of that code in his editor.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost building a state machine just to find substrings.

Try [std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

```
std::string str ("There are two needles in this haystack with needles.");
std::string str2 ("needle");

// different member versions of find in the same order as above:
std::size_t found = str.find(str2);
if (found!=std::string::npos)
  std::cout << "first 'needle' found at: " << found << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

A alternative to your code with only on for loop:

```
bool contains(string input, string target){

        int target_index = 0;

         for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){

            target_index = input.at(i) == target[target_index].at(i) ? target_index + 1 : 0;  

            if(target_character_index + 1 == target.size()) return true; 
         }
         return false;
}

int main()
{
     int size = 0;
     cin>>size;
     string target = "nadia";

     while(size-- > 0){
       string input = "";
       cin>>input;
       cout>>contains(input, target) ? "YES" : "NO";
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your loops start with `i = 0`.

That means you're just looking for the characters `n`, `a`, `d`, `i` and `a`, individually, anywhere in the string, with no relation to where the other desired characters are found.

You're not doing a substring search at all. This is simply the wrong algorithm.

You also only tested inputs with "nadia" all found in a row; if you'd tested e.g. "diana" as well, you'd have discovered the false positive result that was undoubtedly triggered by the online testing program.